# Should zero as a solution to an equation always be checked when applying the function $\frac{1}{x}$ on both sides?

Tags: functions, soft-question, roots

Here is an example when zero is a root to an equation, but we lose it because we divide both sides by $x$(because, we suppose that $x\neq 0$): $$x(x-1)=0\Leftrightarrow  x-1 = 0 \Leftrightarrow  x=1$$ In what cases can this occur?

Comment: you answered ur own question bro

Comment: you should check for the roots you're eliminating. for example, if you are dividing by $(x-2)$, quickly check  whether 2 is a root

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you divide the equation by $f(x)$, you need to know that $f(x)=0$ is also a possible solution.

---

Even better, don't divide. Rather, rewrite the equation. For example, say you are solving

$$x^2\sin(x) = x(x+1)$$

and want to divide by $x$. Instead of dividing by $x$, rewrite the equation to $$x(x\sin x - x - 1) = 0$$

and then use the fact that $A\cdot B = 0 \iff A=0$ or $B=0$. So, this tells you that either $x=0$, or $x\sin x - x - 1 = 0$.

The result is the same, since $x=0$ is the solution you need to check if you divide by $0$, and $x\sin x - x - 1 = 0$ is the equation you get after dividing. However, conceptually, this is a much clearer way of solving it.

Comment: Yes, but that's too broad. For example here: $$2=\frac{x-2}{x-3}$$ You always know that $3$ can't be a solution. So, my question is in what other cases can we lose a solution except in the case in my question?

Comment: @LearningMath You lose a solution when **you** divide an equation by something that can be $0$. When you **start** with the equation $2=\frac{x-2}{x-3}$, **you** didn't divide anything by anything, so you didn't lose any solution.

Comment: I suppose that it should be checked every time $0$ is in the domain of the function defined by the expression on the right. But I am not really sure about this because I apply this thinking only on the problem I gave in the comment.

Comment: @LearningMath This is exactly why I say in my answer to **not** divide anything by anything. Rather, factor the expression, and use $A\cdot B=0\implies A=0\lor B=0$.